# c++ explicit keyword cause compile error: template in template type cannot be resolved?

Tags: c++, templates

I encountered a compile problem, and simplified my problem as the following code blocks:

```
// implement fix point number with N-digit fraction part.
// To make example short for my question, we just use another 'k' 
// to make template meaningful
template <int N>
struct fixpt {
    int n;
    int k;

    explicit fixpt()
        : k(N)
    {}

    explicit fixpt(int _n)
        : n(_n), k(N)
    {}


#ifdef BAD_EXPLICIT
          explicit     // <=== this is where the problem raises.
#endif
    fixpt(const fixpt &rhs)
        : n(rhs.n), k(N)
    {}

     fixpt & operator -= (const fixpt &rhs) {
        n -= rhs.n;
        return *this;
    }

    friend  fixpt operator - (fixpt lhs, const fixpt &rhs)
    {
        lhs -= rhs;
        return lhs;
    }
};

// implement a (x,y) coordinated planar point.
template <typename T>
struct Point_ {
    T x;
    T y;

     explicit Point_()
    {}

     explicit Point_(T _x, T _y)
        : x(_x), y(_y)
    {}

     Point_ & operator -= (const Point_ &rhs) {
        x -= rhs.x;
        y -= rhs.y;
        return *this;
    }

    friend  Point_ operator - (Point_ lhs, const Point_ &rhs)
    {
        lhs -= rhs;
        return lhs;
    }
};

// implement an algorithm with any 'Point' type as its argument.
template <typename T>
Point_<T> foo(Point_<T> & pt)
{
    Point_<T> a(T(1), T(2));   // <=== this is line 66, the 1st compile error
    Point_<T> b(T(3), T(4));

    Point_<T> A(b-a);

    return Point_<T>(A.x-pt.x, A.y-pt.y);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Point_<fixpt<8> > x;
    x.x = fixpt<8>(10);
    x.y = fixpt<8>(11);

    Point_<fixpt<8> > y(x);

    Point_<fixpt<8> > z;

    z = foo(x);
    return 0;
}
```

When `BAD_EXPLICIT` is defined, the code can not compile, with the first compile error to be: `main.cpp:66: error: no matching function for call to 'fixpt<8>::fixpt(fixpt<8>)'
     Point_<T> a(T(1), T(2));
                           ^`

When `BAD_EXPLICIT` is not defined, the code seems OK to compile.

The error said `no matching function`, but it seems that I have defined a constructor for `fixpt<8>` with correct type as its argument.

My question is: How is that so? In addition, I really want that 'explicit' to be there, to prevent from unintentional uses.  How can I do that?

== NOTE: Question update ==
remove 'inline' and use injected class name, as suggested by Joachim Pileborg, and Sebastian Redl.  (Thanks for the useful tips.)

Comment: On an unrelated note, if you actually define a member function inline in the class, then you don't need the `inline` keyword, it will be implied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, I have the answer to my own question and post it right here:

In fact, I misunderstand what 'explicit' keyword means.  See my other question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129643/explicit-keyword-in-g-has-no-effect-for-simple-constructor-not-copy-assignm).

Now I know 'explicit' only manage the automatic conversions of arguments (including functions for operator overloads).  By using an 'explicit' I can never use  `Point_<fixpt<8> > x = y;`, implicitly or explicitly.  For example, `Point_<fixpt<8>> x = y - z;` are also illegal.   Even `Point_<fixpt<8> > x(y-z)`
is illegal, since result of `y-z` will create a temporal, say `t = y-z`.  But expression similar to `t = y-z` is forbidden, since the corresponding constructor has `explicit` keyword.

You may also think of this question as a duplicate to [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean).

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad idea to make your copy constructor explicit. I don't know what exactly your compiler is doing, but I wouldn't be too surprised if it got confused by this. Just don't make the copy constructor explicit, and you'll be fine.

I also consider it a bad idea (code clutter) to mark functions defined inline in the classes as inline; they're already implicitly inline.

Finally, you can use the injected class name feature of C++ to replace the `fixpt<N>` with `fixpt` within the definition of `fixpt`, just like you do with `Point_`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tips of unnecessary 'inline' and injected class name feature.  However, since explicit is only for the constructor (+ operator overload for/after C++11), I can not agree your point of not using explicit at all.  Yet I admit that my example may not be as good to have the need to use it.  However, this is a simplified example to show the problem.  `explicit` keyword could be useful in a real case.

Comment: Argument passing is a copy-initialization context and can't use explicit constructors.

Comment: I said don't use it for the copy constructor (the constructor taking a single argument of a reference to its own type), not don't use it at all.