# 'explicit' keyword in g++ has no effect for simple constructor (not copy/assignment constructor)?

Tags: c++, g++

Can anyone explain why the following code compiles?  I expect it to get an error where the `double` constant `3.3` can not be converted to `int`, since I declare the constructor to be `explicit`.

```
class A
{
public:
    int n;
    explicit A(int _n);
};

A::A(int _n)
{
    n = _n;
}

int main()
{
    A a(3.3); // <== I expect this line to get an error.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood what the [explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) keyword does.

Comment: Nope, this line will give you error `A b = 24;`

Comment: This is what uniform (i.e. brace-enclosed) initialization is for: `A a{3.3};` would fail because it's a narrowing conversion (double to int).  However `A a(3.3);` does not because narrowing conversions are allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works in the other way around. Let's define in addition to your code

```
void f(A a)
{
}

int main()
{
    A a(3.3); // <== I expect this line to get an error.
    f(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Without the word *explicit* it would compile, with the *explicit* it would report an error. The keyword forbids casting from integer to *A* in situations like this.

Answer (score 2):

> explicit class_name ( params )    (1)
>   explicit operator type ( ) (since C++11)   (2)
>
> 1) specifies that this constructor is only considered for direct initialization (including explicit conversions)
>
> 2) specifies that this user-defined conversion function is only considered for direct initialization (including explicit conversions)

In your case you *are* using direct initialization to construct an instance of type `A` by doing this:

```
A a(3.3);
```

The [explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) keyword does not stop the compiler from implicitly casting your argument from a double type to an int. It stops you from doing something like this:

```
A a = 33;
```